# Testing at certain level of significance if average is more than a given number.

Tags: statistics

So I have this question:

> Test, at the $1\%$ level of significance, whether the average distance someone commutes is more than $15$ km.

Some facts about the model are:

> - Normal Continuous Distribution.
> - Mean is $14.75$.
> - $\sigma = 7.923$
> - Sample Size is $80$.

So far I have tried the following:

Two tailed test with: $a = 0.01$. 
Area of curve to the left is: $0.995$. So $z_c = 2.58$.

Then calculate $z$ to be:

$$z = \frac{14.75 - 15}{\frac{7.923}{\sqrt(80)}} = -0.28255$$

So since: $2.58 > -0.28255$ it is not evident at $1\%$ level of significance that the average distance commuted is more than $15$km.

I'm fairly certain I made a mistake here, or some basic premise might be wrong. If anyone can help me figure out what I may have done wrong, as well as possibly explain the concept so I can apply it to other similar problems, I would be immensely grateful.

Comment: Why did you do a two tailed test?

Comment: @imranfat I'm honestly not sure. I don't even know if it's applicable or not. I was just trying to understand (and apply) something I read of a similar problem online.

Comment: With sample mean below 15 you will certainly not be able to reject null hypothesis to conclude population mean $\mu > 0.$ Answer (+1) gives more detail. // If this is the _exact_ question asked, then you cannot reject $H_0: \mu \le 15$ at level 1% (or any other reasonable level).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when reading through your data more detailed, there are couple of things not right here. You want to test if the commuting distance, based on your sample data, is more than 15 km. That clearly suggest a one tailed test, not two. Whether or not you SHOULD be doing a one tailed test, is a different question, but the way how it is worded, I would pick a one tailed (that's a right tailed) test. Now when examining the sample data, there is another issue: Your sample data has a mean that is actually less than 15 km. So your sample actually suggests that the average commuting distance of the whole population would be less than 15 km, not more. This is why your calculate $z$ score and the $z$ score you have from your significance level, have opposite signs, which is odd.If you want to test if the commuting distance of the population is truly more than 15 km, wouldn't we at least expect that our sample (80 individuals is not a small sample) have a mean that is above 15 km? The way the question is now, doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: I agree it might not make sense, but this was the data as I was given it. But I'll try and figure out how a one-tailed test is.

Comment: In a right tailed test, you would at least expect the sample mean to be above 15 km if that is what you want to test. Then the statistical question becomes how much the sample mean has to be above 15 in order to be considered significant. (Upon which you would reject the null hypothesis). At least then the question makes sense